# List of objects that need different logic

Tags: angularjs

I want to display a list of events of very different types that should have different UI logic. Yes, they have common properties (like name, date/time, location etc) but also sets of custom properties that can be simple text, typeahead items, drop down lists etc. Depending on the specific event type (there will be tens of them) I need to handle user input in different ways. For example, on select a typeahead item I want to clear two other fields etc.
I'm gonna display those events using ng-repeat and dynamically load template views depending on the specific event type. These views will have proper controllers that are specific to the business object. I still haven't make it work but please advice me.

1. Is loading type-related views with controllers inside is a good idea
   for this task?
2. Would directives instead of controllers be better?
3. Is there a way to dynamically set controller/directive name in the HTML attribute?
4. Any other advices?

Answer (score 1):

1. yes
2. yes, use directives.  If you have a base event definition, it is probably best to define an element directive for that and use attribute directives to extend/customize the functionality for different event types.
3. not exactly, but you can use `ng-switch` on your list item element.

example:

```
<li ng-repeat="event in events" ng-switch on="event.type">
    <my-event event="event" first-type ng-switch-when="type1"></my-event>
    <my-event event="event" second-type ng-switch-when="type2"></my-event>
    <my-event event="event" third-type ng-switch-when="type3"></my-event>
    <my-event event="event" ng-switch-default></my-event>
</li>
```

4. Use `require: 'myEvent'` in your extending directives to gain access to the base `myEvent` controller.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/plong0/pen/bZQdJJ)

Comment: And the event-specific logic should be written in the in-line controllers of directives?

Comment: if you do the approach I suggest, each event type (ex. `firstType`) would be its own directive and could have its own controller + template, but still have access to the base `myEvent` controller via `require`.

Comment: using directives replaces need for doing things like `<div ng-include="my-template.tpl.html" ng-controller="MyController"></div>` with a nicely encapsulated `<my-directive></my-directive>`.  In your `myDirective` directive definittion you would set `controller: 'MyController', template: 'my-template.tpl.html'`

Comment: There will be 40-50 events typesso this will need as many html elements what I don't like. Trying to find away to dynamically eval proper directive name...

Comment: Ok... in that case you can dynamically generate directives using the `$compile` service and `element.append()` them into the DOM.  Or else it might actually make more sense to use `ng-include` and `ng-controller` with `{{event.type}}` embedded in their name some how (ex. `ng-include="event-{{event.type}}.tpl.html"`).

Comment: This is how I've made it work for now:   
<div evt evt-ctrl="getCtrlName"></div>  
...  
in the rootScope initialization:  
$rootScope.getCtrlName = function($scope) { return $scope.EventType + 'Ctrl'; }

Comment: and the directive:         .directive('evt', function() {
            return {
                controller: '@@',
                name: "evtCtrl"
            }
        });